# Module "Users/../node_modules/react-router" has no exported member 'match'

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, history

I upgraded react-router and react-router-dom to `6.0.0-beta.0` from v4 and since then I'm getting this error. I'm not using match.path anywhere in the app.

```
dependencies {
 "@types/react-router": "^4.0.28",
 "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.2.7",
 "react-router": "^6.0.0-beta.0",
 "react-router-dom": "^6.0.0-beta.0",
 "history": "^5.0.0"
}
```

```
/Users/..../../node_modules/@types/react-router-dom/index.d.ts
(10,10): Module '"../../../../../../../../Users/allans/Desktop/../../node_modules/react-router"' has no exported member 'match'
```

Not enough documentation is available to this issue.

Comment: Can you post a stack trace for the error?

Comment: I just edited my question. It does not give stack trace just one line of error @Linda Paiste

Answer (score 6):

remove **@types/react-router** and **@types/react-router-dom** from package.json

Comment: The essence of your post has already been given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67094169/10871073). Please refrain from simply repeating/confirming other answers.

Comment: That answer is kind of ambiguous.  "looks like we do not require @types/react-router and @types/react-router-dom in package.json file" -- does this mean they are not requiring them and they should? Or does it mean that they are including them and they do not need to?  Zhuang's answer succinctly described the solution and fixed the problem.  The other answer requires reading a post and inferring the intention of the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this error was resolved by removing `react-router` from package.json and keeping `react-router dom` only

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and according to [this post](https://typescript.tv/react/upgrade-to-react-router-v6/)! looks like we do not require @types/react-router and @types/react-router-dom in package.json file.